# Button in Sencha Touch 2 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, events, button, extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

In the launch() function of App.js file I have this code:

```
launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('SenchaApp.view.Main'));
},
```

In the View.js file, instead, I have this code:

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', { text: 'Click me',
                                        handler: function() {
                                              alert('You clicked the button!')
                                      }}
                        );


Ext.define("SenchaApp.view.Main", {
         extend: 'Ext.Panel',
         config: { items: [button]}
});
```

The problem is that the events of the button never fire, so the button doesn't work.

What's the reason??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does work but you are not getting the alert :)

Try this:

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', { text: 'Click me',
    handler: function() {
        console.log('You clicked the button!')
        Ext.Msg.alert('hey', 'You clicked the button!');
    }}
);
```

Comment: Nothing... the problem persists. The button isn't clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way:

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Button',
    handler : function(){alert("You clicked the button!");}
});
Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'container', padding: 10, items: [button] });
```

OR

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    items: {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'My Button',
        handler : function(){Ext.Msg.alert('Msg','You clicked the button!');}
    }
});
```

Hope it will help you!!!